# Android - Firestore - SearchView

Tags: android, firebase, firestore

como posso realizar uma pesquisa com o firestore? por exemplo, se digitar uma cidade, listar os dados relacionados à essa cidade. Valeu

Comment: Tem um exemplo de como usar o firestore aqui: https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-android  Além dos documentos em: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/?hl=pt-br

Comment: tranquilo, valeu !